# How to utilize class inheritance?

Tags: python

Trying to understand inheritance. The `PartTimeEmployee` class should inherit attributes from the `Employee` class. But I get errors trying "tap" into the `ReturnName` method to print out the `PartTimeEmployee` information.

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, employee_name):
        self.employee_name = employee_name

    def ReturnName(self, employee_name):
        self.employee_name = employee_name
        return employee_name

    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
        self.hours = hours
        return hours * 20.00


class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
        self.hours = hours
        return hours * 12.00

ft_emp = Employee("Mike")
ft_emp_name = ft_emp.ReturnName("Mike")

pt_emp = PartTimeEmployee("Bill")
#pt_emp_name = pt_emp.ReturnName("Bill")

ft_pay = ft_emp.calculate_wage(40)
#pt_pay = pt_emp_name.calculate_wage(20)

print "Full time employee %s made $%d for the week." %(ft_emp_name, ft_pay)
#print "Part time employee %s made $%d for the week." %(pt_emp_name, pt_pay)

>>>
Full time employee Mike made $800 for the week.
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: As as side note, it is a bad idea to have a method called "returnX" and use  it to *set* X.

Comment: Please show the exact error.

Comment: With what you have so far, I wouldn't even use inheritance. I would just make `wage` an attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commented line:

```
#pt_pay = pt_emp_name.calculate_wage(20)
```

should be:

```
pt_pay = pt_emp.calculate_wage(20)
```

Otherwise it is an attempt to call method calculate_wage on a string object.

Comment: Thanks piokuc, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

What you really have are two different kinds of employees, full-time and part-time. As such, I might use a design like this:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, wage):
        self.name = name
        self.wage = wage

    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
        return hours * self.wage


class FullTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name, 20)


class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name, 12)
```

`Employee` contains everything that is common to either type of employee. The subclasses contain information specific to each type, so far just the hourly wage paid each. Notice there is no `ReturnName` method. If you want an employee's name, just access the `name` attribute directly.

```
ft_emp = FullTimeEmployee("Mike")
ft_emp_name = ft_emp.name

pt_emp = PartTimeEmployee("Bill")
pt_emp_name = pt_emp.name

ft_pay = ft_emp.calculate_wage(40)
pt_pay = pt_emp.calculate_wage(20)

print "Full time employee %s made $%d for the week." %(ft_emp_name, ft_pay)
print "Part time employee %s made $%d for the week." %(pt_emp_name, pt_pay)
```

Comment: Thanks chepner, much more efficient this way.

Comment: chepner, I wasn't able to get this to run.